# How to backup the cassandra running in docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra, backup, containers

We have cassandra cluster with 3 nodes running in our environment in docker container. Earlier we used snapshotter but as we have recently migrated it to docker how can we achieve the backup of cassandra. Is there any way to take the incremental backups.

Thanks in Advance.
Kiran Kumar

Comment: I would think your cassandra is persistent by mounting `var/lib/cassandra`  to somewhere? maybe the host. Than you can create backups of those folders on a certain moment and upload them to some storage server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with `Snapshotter` then you can use `Snapshotter` with docker also. just mount cassandra docker volume in host somewhere and take backup as usual with `Snapshotter`.

you can mount docker Cassandra directory `/var/lib/cassandra` to `/opt/cassandra` on host system using command.

```
docker run -d--name web -v /opt/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra cassandra_container
```

After that you can take incremental backup of `/opt/cassandra` using `snapshotter`.

OR

If you planning to explore other docker volume plugin then visit  [available docker volume plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#/volume-plugins)